# How to convert an int to a float?

Tags: javascript, types, int

I have an int, say, `var myInt = 24` and I need it to display it as a float like this: `24,000`. Is it even possible in javascript?

Important: converted float should be a number, not a string

Comment: JavaScript only has a Number type that stores floating point values.There is no int.

Comment: @8protons: Some countries use commas as a decimal mark rather than a point - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma

Comment: "Important: converted float should be a number, not a string" - there is no such thing in JavaScript. A `Number` is a `Number` and can be _represented_ in different ways, depending even on locale. Those representations are strings. Even a `Number` added to the DOM is still a string. It's representation is that returned by `Number.toString()`.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv, thanks! that is what I needed to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toFixed()` to add zeros after the decimal point.

```js
var myInt = 24;
console.log(myInt.toFixed(3));
```

Comment: Yep, works perfectly! Thanks! I saw that my question is a duplicate thought, so it probably will be deleted :)

Comment: Actually it is converted to string. It's not what I need :(

Comment: Actually, it will be not deleted :)

Comment: Yes `toFixed` returns string but you can then use parseFloat and it will return number https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/616/

Comment: It gives 24 back, not 24.000 :)

Comment: I need 3 extra zero's at the end, so it will be a float number

Comment: I don't think its possible https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/618/, if you just have zeros they will be trimmed, unless you use to `toFixed`, and then you can use `parseFloat` again if you need number.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how I can use these two on a project. Thanks!

Comment: "I need 3 extra zero's at the end, so it will be a float number" - `24` and `24.0` in JavaScript are both `Number` instances. All of them are floats. You can decide to interpret them yourself as integers, but to JavaScript they are all floats. `24.000` is a _representation_ of the float `24`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Number.toFixed:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
var int = 24
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(int.toFixed(3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```